# Pivot Table "Incorrect Syntax"

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to group my sql table together, but I am receiving an "incorrect syntax"

```
Declare @pet varchar(max)

SET @pet = (select petsName from pets);

select * from pets

AS basedata

Pivot (
 count(PetID)

 for petsName in (' + @pet+ ') <-- error here
)

as pivottable
```

Why am I receiving an incorrect syntax near @pet?

Thanks

Comment: What is the structure of your pets table? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with your pivot query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql for this

```
DECLARE @pet VARCHAR(max)

SET @pet = (SELECT ',' + Quotename(petsName) -- Quotename is used to escape illegal characters
            FROM   pets
            FOR xml path('')); -- to concatenate the records 

SET @pet = Stuff(@pet, 1, 1, '') -- to remove the leading comma 

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(8000) = ''

SET @sql = '
select * from pets AS basedata
Pivot ( count(PetID)
for petsName in (' + @pet + ') ) as pivottable' 

exec sp_executesql @sql -- to execute the dynamically framed string
```

Another mistake in your query is, you are trying to assign `petsName` to `@pet` variable.

```
SET @pet = (select petsName from pets);
```

But a variable can store only one record. So you need to concatenate the records into one single record separated by comma. Then the variable can be used in pivot list

```
SET @pet = (SELECT ',' + Quotename(petsName)
            FROM   pets
            FOR xml path(''));
```